# How might one go about proving this poorly worded theorem about divisibility with the number 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I was messing around and found something interesting, at least to me. Although I may not know how to delicately word this, so I hope it is clear.

Claim: Each natural number $n$, whose sequence of digits are represented by the string $S$ is divisible by $3$ if the length of $S$ is divisible by $3$, and each consecutive sequence of $3$ characters in $S$ are identical numbers.

Probably this idea can be pinned down even further. But even with what I have added, the part where it can be longer than $3$ digits being the same number, it seems still challenging at least for me to prove. Maybe if we first prove that a $3$ digit number is divisible by $3$ if each digit is the same then it will be easier? Or perhaps [Divisibility by Liljevalch’s theorem](http://amca01.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/divisibility-tests-and-liljevalchs-theorem/) is better yet. But in any case we can say that the three consecutive digits sum to $3m$ (where $m$ is the identical digit), which is divisible by $3$.

How might you go about something like this. But probably more important, how do I first word this theorem better since I am not yet literate with such things? Perhaps without needing to talk about strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Theorem.** Let $N$ be a natural number whose decimal expansion is of the form:
$$N= a_0(1+10+10^2)+a_1(10^3+10^4+10^6)+\cdots+a_{n}(10^{3n}+10^{3n+1}+10^{3n+2}),$$
for some $n\geq 0$ and $a_i\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ for each $i=0,\ldots,n$. Then $N$ is divisible by $3$.

**Proof.** Let us reduce $N\bmod 3$. We obtain:

\begin{align*}
N &\equiv a_0(1+10+10^2)+a_1(10^3+10^4+10^6)+\cdots+a_{n}(10^{3n}+10^{3n+1}+10^{3n+2})\\
& \equiv a_0(1+1+1)+a_1(1+1+1)+\cdots+a_n(1+1+1)\\
&\equiv a_0\cdot 0 + a_1\cdot 0 + \cdots + a_n\cdot 0 \\
& \equiv 0 \bmod 3.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $N\equiv 0\bmod 3$ and this is equivalent to $N$ being divisible by $3$.

Comment: Beat me to it, and exactly right. +1

Comment: The contrast in the clarity between my claim and your theorem is palpable, well done sir.

Comment: Notice also that once you have the correct statement, the proof is trivial!